# AWS Amazon Linux MySQL Yum Update Failure

Tags: linux, mysql, amazon-web-services, yum

I SSH'd into my AWS EC2 instance using an Amazon Linux AMI, and it told me to run the `sudo yum update` command for security updates. When I did, it ultimately failed to update MySQL.

*I don't know if this is the cause, but please note that my MySQL is setup with mount binds to an attached EBS filesystem via: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1663?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1

Here's the output:

```
[ec2-user@ip /]$ sudo yum update
Loaded plugins: priorities, security, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main                                                                                                                      | 2.1 kB     00:00     
amzn-updates                                                                                                                   | 2.3 kB     00:00     
Setting up Update Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql55-common.x86_64 0:5.5.32-1.35.amzn1 will be updated
---> Package mysql55-common.x86_64 0:5.5.32-1.36.amzn1 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

======================================================================================================================================================
 Package                              Arch                         Version                                   Repository                          Size
======================================================================================================================================================
Updating:
 mysql55-common                       x86_64                       5.5.32-1.36.amzn1                         amzn-updates                        47 k

Transaction Summary
======================================================================================================================================================
Upgrade       1 Package(s)

Total download size: 47 k
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
mysql55-common-5.5.32-1.36.amzn1.x86_64.rpm                                                                                    |  47 kB     00:00     
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
  Updating   : mysql55-common-5.5.32-1.36.amzn1.x86_64                                                                                            1/2 
Error unpacking rpm package mysql55-common-5.5.32-1.36.amzn1.x86_64
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /etc/my.cnf: cpio: rename
  Verifying  : mysql55-common-5.5.32-1.36.amzn1.x86_64                                                                                            1/2 
mysql55-common-5.5.32-1.35.amzn1.x86_64 was supposed to be removed but is not!
  Verifying  : mysql55-common-5.5.32-1.35.amzn1.x86_64                                                                                            2/2 

Failed:
  mysql55-common.x86_64 0:5.5.32-1.35.amzn1                                 mysql55-common.x86_64 0:5.5.32-1.36.amzn1                                

Complete!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually it happens when file has immutable (i) flag set for security reasons.

`lsattr /etc/my.cnf`

`chattr -i /etc/my.cnf`

In case of Amazon EBS, looks like file is bound to one on the EBS volume: just `umount /etc/my.cnf`, run update and `bind` it again.

Comment: Hi @GioMac. Thanks for your quick response! I ran `lsattr /etc/my.cnf` and received this output: `[ec2-user@ip /]$ lsattr /etc/my.cnf
--------------- /etc/my.cnf`

Comment: You're Welcome. Welcome to serverfault. Now it should work. Please update us with results :)

Comment: I ran both commands, attempted to `sudo yum update` again and the same error occurred :/

Comment: Then looks like file is not writable (`mount|grep etc`, `ls -l /etc/my.cnf`) or locked (`lsof|grep my.cnf`)

Comment: `mount|grep etc` outputs `/mysqlvol/etc/my.cnf on /etc/my.cnf type none (rw,bind)`. The file is 644. `lsof|grep my.cnf` outputs nothing. Any clues? Thanks again :)

Comment: looks like your configuration file is "binded" to the one that is on the EBS volume, did you run `mount` with bind for this particular file it to be so? You can actually `umount /etc/my.cnf` and mount it back after rpm installation, but, anyway, how did it come?

Comment: Beautiful. Unmounting, updating and remounting did the trick! Thank you so much for your help. Should I mark this answer as correct, or do you want to add another answer with the `umount` and I can check that?

Comment: Good... I'll update the answer accordingly, so other users can find it :)
Yes